# Loading Bar inside Button that animates to the remaining time of an audiofile

Tags: android, animation, button, media-player

I have a button that plays a sound. When it starts playing, I change the background of the button from red to black (v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button)). 
After the audio is done playing (mediaplayer.getDuration()), the background of the button is changed back to red.

Now what I want is that when you click the button, the button should start an animation on itself, showing some sort of progress bar that has the same duration as the audio time.
So instead of changing from red to black instantly, I need some sort of transition, painting or fading of the new black color. I am not sure what to use here. Here you see a mockup how it should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Visit this lInk it is very usefull to you. 
just download zip file and see demo.
[Android Proccess Button](https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/android-process-button)

Comment: Thank you, that looks really promising!